# Setting up Rabbit MQ Heartbeat with Kombu

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, heartbeat, kombu

**Edit:**

The main issue is the 3rd party rabbitmq machine seems to kill idle connections every now and then. That's when I start getting "Broken Pipe" exceptions. The only way to gets comms. back to normal is for me to kill the processes and restart them. I assume there's a better way?

--

I'm a little lost here. I am connecting to a 3rd party RabbitMQ server to push messages to. Every now and then all the sockets on their machine gets dropped and I end up getting a "Broken Pipe" exception.

I've been told to implement a heartbeat check in my code but I'm not sure how exactly. I've found some info here: http://kombu.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changelog.html#version-2-3-0 but no real example code.

Do I only need to add "?heartbeat=x" to the connection string? Does Kombu do the rest? I see I need to call "Connection.heartbeat_check()" at "x/2". Should I create a periodic task to call this? How does the connection get re-established?

I'm using:

- celery==3.0.12
- kombu==2.5.4

My code looks like this right now. A simple Celery task gets called to send the message through to the 3rd party RabbitMQ server (removed logging and comments to keep it short, basic enough):

```
class SendMessageTask(Task):
    name = "campaign.backends.send"
    routing_key = "campaign.backends.send"
    ignore_result = True
    default_retry_delay = 60 # 1 minute.
    max_retries = 5

    def run(self, send_to, message, **kwargs):
    payload = "Testing message"

    try:
        conn = BrokerConnection(
        hostname=HOSTNAME,
        port=PORT,
        userid=USER_ID,
        password=PASSWORD,
        virtual_host=VHOST
        )

        with producers[conn].acquire(block=True) as producer:
        publish = conn.ensure(producer, producer.publish, errback=sending_errback, max_retries=3)
        publish(
            body=payload,
            routing_key=OUT_ROUTING_KEY,
            delivery_mode=2,
            exchange=EXCHANGE,
            serializer=None,
            content_type='text/xml',
            content_encoding = 'utf-8'
        )

    except Exception, ex:
        print ex
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you certainly can add heartbeat support to a producer, it makes more sense for consumer processes.

Enabling heartbeats means that you have to send heartbeats regularly, e.g. if the heartbeat is set to 1 second, then you have to send a heartbeat every second or more or the remote will close the connection.

This means that you have to use a separate thread or use async io to reliably send heartbeats in time, and since a connection cannot be shared between threads this leaves us with async io.

The good news is that you probably won't get much benefit adding heartbeats to a produce-only connection.

Comment: Fair enough :) What then is the best way to handle the "Broken Pipe" exception I'm getting every now and then? Is there a way to check the connection, if it's down, re-connect? Thanks again.

Comment: I think this answer in another thread may give you some hints? https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/carrot-users/RIWdNE5TK2g

Comment: This looks like what I need. Made the changes to the code, let you know if it takes care of my connection woes :)

Comment: Awesome, it seems to be working. Haven't gotten any more "Broken Pipe" exceptions since implementing my Producer like shown in the Google Group. Thanks @asksol.

Comment: why is it not beneficial to add timeout on the producer side?